Maximum call stack error occurred while building a mongoose multidimensional database
After building a database for the company's task checklist, a maximum call stack error occurred while creating company data.
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
The above error occurred in the <NotFoundErrorBoundary> component:

The code for the constructed schema and data creation is as follows.
Company.ts
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_DB_URL
    ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MONGO_DB_URL
    : ""
);

const companySchema = new Schema<CompanyType>({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "기업 이름은 필수 요소입니다."],
  },
  image: String,
  isAcquired: Boolean,
  authExpiresIn: Date,
  currentProcess: String,
  mainProcess: {
    type: [{ type: String }],
    default: [
      "영업 및 착수 안내",
      "데이터 수집",
      "인증서 신청",
      "심사",
      "인증서 발급",
    ],
  },
  salesAndInfoStartUp: {
    name: String,
    isPass: Boolean,
    start: Date,
    end: Date,
    subProcess: [
      {
        type: {
          subName: String,
          isPass: Boolean,
          detail: [
            {
              type: {
                content: String,
                checked: Boolean,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});

const companyModel =
  (models.Company as CompanyModel) ||
  model<CompanyType, CompanyModel>("Company", companySchema);

export default companyModel;

actions.ts
const addCompanyFormSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
});

const AddCompany = addCompanyFormSchema;

export const addCompany = async (formData: FormData) => {
  const { name } = AddCompany.parse({
    name: formData.get("name"),
  });

  await companyModel.create({
    name,
    image: "",
    currentProcess: "영업 및 착수안내",
    isAcquired: false,
    mainProcess: [
      "영업 및 착수 안내",
      "데이터 수집",
      "인증서 신청",
      "심사",
      "인증서 발급",
    ],
    salesAndInfoStartUp: {
      name: "영업 및 착수안내",
      isPass: false,
      start: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 9),
      subProcess: [
        {
          subName: "목적 정의",
          isPass: false,
          detail: [
            {
              content: "연구 수행이유",
              checked: false,
            },
            {
              content: "연구결과 활용처",
              checked: false,
            },
            {
              content: "연구결과 제출처",
              checked: false,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  revalidatePath("/search");
  redirect("/search");
};

I know this structure is unreasonable, but it is difficult to change because it is a structure requested by the company.
Or is there a way to rebuild the database by changing it to a tree structure or linked list structure instead of a multidimensional array?
